# oci_fetch_all equivalent for pdo?

Tags: php, postgresql, oracle

I'm trying to get result from a postgres database with the fetchAll() function. But I have to get the same result from an Oracle DB and it doesn't work with the fetchAll() function.

With fetchall() i have an array with index numbers and each array represent a row from the db, but with oci_fetch_all each array have an array with the column name as index, and each array represent a column from the db and that's what I need

Postgres :

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare($req);

   $stmt->execute();
   
   $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

output :

array(4) {

```
  [0]=>
  array(14) {
    ["PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    [0]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    ["Critère"]=>
    string(6) "02_PPA"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "02_PPA"
    ["type_prescription"]=>
    string(6) "risque"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "risque"
    ["Aire parcelle (m²)"]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    ["Aire de lintersection (m²)"]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    ["%"]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    ["trig_comm"]=>
    NULL
    [6]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(14) {
    ["PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    [0]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    ["Critère"]=>
    string(8) "04_zone1"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "04_zone1"
    ["type_prescription"]=>
    string(3) "PDU"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "PDU"
    ["Aire parcelle (m²)"]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    ["Aire de lintersection (m²)"]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    ["%"]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    ["trig_comm"]=>
    NULL
    [6]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(14) {
    ["PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    [0]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    ["Critère"]=>
    string(5) "07_MH"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "07_MH"
    ["type_prescription"]=>
    string(10) "patrimoine"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "patrimoine"
    ["Aire parcelle (m²)"]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    ["Aire de lintersection (m²)"]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    ["%"]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    ["trig_comm"]=>
    NULL
    [6]=>
    NULL
  }
  [3]=>
  array(14) {
    ["PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    [0]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    ["Critère"]=>
    string(20) "18_OAP_communautaire"
    [1]=>
    string(20) "18_OAP_communautaire"
    ["type_prescription"]=>
    string(3) "OAP"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "OAP"
    ["Aire parcelle (m²)"]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    ["Aire de lintersection (m²)"]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "298.62"
    ["%"]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    ["trig_comm"]=>
    string(3) "CEN"
    [6]=>
    string(3) "CEN"
  }
}
```

ORACLE :

```
  if (oci_execute($ora_req)) {
        // récupération des infos dans la base de donnée 
        $nrows = oci_fetch_all($ora_req, $res);
        //  Stockage des infos dans le tableau 
        array_push($arrPrescriptionS, $res);
    }
```

OUTPUT :

```
array(0) { }

array(7) {
  ["'PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S'"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
    [3]=>
    string(18) "PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S"
  }
  ["Critère"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "02_PPA"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "04_zone1"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "07_MH"
    [3]=>
    string(20) "18_OAP_communautaire"
  }
  ["TYPE_PRESCRIPTION"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "02"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "04"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "07"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "18"
  }
  ["Aire parcelle (m²)"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "298,62"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "298,62"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "298,62"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "298,62"
  }
  ["Aire de l'intersection (m²)"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "298,62"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "298,62"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "298,62"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "298,62"
  }
  ["%"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "100"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "100"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "100"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
  ["TRIG_COMM"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    NULL
    [2]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    string(3) "CEN"
  }
}
```

thank's

Comment: Honestly, I would not like to work with what the oci_fetch_all is doing to it. Thats difficult to iterate through rows of data. I do not know of a built-in PDO method for that, but you can get the same effect by looping the rows and building a new array of mashed up columns like oracle is doing.

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php): *$flags*: *OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW*: The outer array will contain one sub-array per query row. *OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_COLUMN*: The outer array will contain one sub-array per query column. **This is the default.**

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in PDO. PDO doesn't return results indexed by column names. This behaviour is not very intuitive when writing code, so it's best avoided. Use the normal fetch modes, which order results by rows.

If you need to write some shim for backwards compatibility you can do it yourself with nested loops.

```
$s = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM bar");

$allByColumns = [];
foreach ($s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $index => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        $allByColumns[$column][$index] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($allByColumns);
```